# compute button in c# does not work

Tags: c#

```
    private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == (char)13) 
      {  
            if(textBox1.Text !="")
        {
                listBox1.Items.Add(textBox1.Text);
                textBox1.Text="";
        }
      }
 }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i, n;
        double x, m;
        n = listBox1.Items.Count;
        m = 0;
        for (i=0;i<n;i=i++)
    {
            x=Convert.ToInt32(listBox1.Items[i]);
            m = m + 1;
       }   
        textBox2.Text=Convert.ToString(m);
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(listBox1.SelectedIndex);
    }
}
    }
```

this should be a counting cycle, very simple and all this is my very important school assignment please help when i click on button1 it freeze my computer for a minute i then need to go to stop debuging everything else work perfect please help my this is very important for me

Comment: Why do you declare `x` as a double and then initialize it with `Int32`?  What are you doing with `x` in the first place?

Comment: Who taught you to write `i=i++`?

Comment: Your loop increment `i=i++` looks suspicious: you might get away with it in C# precedence rules (I can't remember) but you really just want `i=i+1` or `i++` (or even `++i`).

Comment: @Rup It's well-defined in C#. But the side effect of `++` happens before the side effect of `=`, so it ends up storing the same value it already had.

Comment: @hvd Thanks: I knew it was well-defined, but not exactly how. And IMO in general if something looks confusing it shouldn't be written that way anyway.

Answer (score 1):

thank you very much for helping i put jus i++ and now it looks it is working.]

```
     private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == (char)13) 
      {  
            if(textBox1.Text !="")
        {
                listBox1.Items.Add(textBox1.Text);
                textBox1.Text="";
        }
      }
 }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i, n;
        double x, m;
        n = listBox1.Items.Count;
        m = 0;
        for (i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
            x=Convert.ToDouble(listBox1.Items[i]);
            m = m + x;
       }   
        textBox2.Text=Convert.ToString(m);
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(listBox1.SelectedIndex);
    }
}
    }
```